# Want to add rspec to my rails 3 app, what do I need to do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, rspec

I updated my GEMFile with:

```
 group :development, :test do

    gem 'rspec'
    gem 'webrat'
    gem 'rspec-rails'
 end
```

And ran bundle install.

Now I already have a HomeController, so I manually created this:

```
/spec/controllers/home_controller_spec.rb
```

I don't have an about page so I started my test off with:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe HomeController do

  describe "Get 'about'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'about'
      response.should be_success
    end
  end


end
```

Now I did:

```
rspec spec/
```

**Do I need to update some other files for rspec to work, don't understand this error message.**

UPDATE

I changed the if to it, now I'm getting:

```
file to load -- spec_helper (LoadError)
    from /Users/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /Users/someuser/dev/rscs/example.com/spec/controllers/home_controller_spec.rb:1
    from /Users/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@rails3/gems/rspec-core-2.2.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:327:in `load'
    from /Users/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@rails3/gems/rspec-core-2.2.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:327:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@rails3/gems/rspec-core-2.2.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:327:in `map'
    from /Users/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@rails3/gems/rspec-core-2.2.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:327:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@rails3/gems/rspec-core-2.2.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:18:in `run'
    from /Users/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@rails3/gems/rspec-core-2.2.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:55:in `run_in_process'
    from /Users/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@rails3/gems/rspec-core-2.2.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:46:in `run'
    from /Users/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@rails3/gems/rspec-core-2.2.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `autorun'
    from /Users/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@rails3/bin/rspec:19
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the top line of the backtrace.

```
/Users/someuser/dev/rscs/example.com/spec/controllers/home_controller_spec.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected kDO, expecting kTHEN or ':' or '\n' or ';' (SyntaxError)
```

That error message points to a syntax error in your spec file—namely, on line 6, there is a `do` where it was not expected. That's where you should check first.

```
if "should be successful" do
```

I'm betting you meant that `if` to be an `it` ;) `it` is the RSpec method for defining a particular aspect of the class to test, and it, unlike the `if` operator, can take a block.

Comment: shame on me, I was certain it was a configuration issue and not the actual rspec code that I wrote, too bad you can't test for that!

Comment: Glad it's all working out :) Here's your friendly reminder to accept the answer once StackOverflow will let you :D

Comment: see my update, it didn't work just yet (and I will accept don't ya worry!)

Comment: hmm..what should spec_helper look like?  is it auto generated or?

Comment: @Blankman: sounds like the `spec_helper` file can't be found. Have you run `rails generate rspec` yet? It should live at `spec/spec_helper.rb`

Comment: it says it can't find the generator, but doing gem list I see both rspec (2.2) and rspec-rails (2.2.1)..I'm running RVM with rails 3.0.3 and ruby 1.8.7

Comment: yay! my test is failing now, i've never been so happy about something failing!

Comment: @Blankman: heh. Whoops. Glad you tracked that one down :) Congrats on the failing!